# Nonlinear Dynamics: How to tell the stability of fixed points?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

I understand how to find the stability of fixed points by using $f'(x)$ and inserting the values of the fixed points into that. However, I can't figure out how to tell the stability in systems such as

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = a + \sin(x) + \cos(2x)$$

In situations like this, the value of the fixed points varies as '$a$' changes, which I have no trouble finding, its just defining their stability that I struggle with.

Comment: Your question seems too broad. As a starting point, it seems you meant $a$ is time-varying. So you'll enter the realm of nonlinear time-varying systems whose stability analysis requires specific tools such as [Lyapunov method](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/JOUR/027.PDF).

Comment: In the case of the question I took the system from, a is a parameter unrelated to time t, but I rushed and didn't clarify, my bad, the stress of exams is getting to me!

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume a system of this type

$$\dot{x}(t)=f(x;a)$$

with the equilibrium point $x_\text{eq}$. In this $a$ is a parameter. In this kind of problem, the equilibrium point is a function of the parameter $a$ (called bifurcation parameter in this context).

In order to obtain the equilibrium point(s) it is necessary to solve the nonlinear equation

$$0 = f(x_\text{eq};a)$$
$$\text{here: } 0 = a+\sin x_\text{eq}+1-2\sin^2x_\text{eq}$$

Then the stability of the equilibrium point can be obtained by Lyapunov's indirect method (also known as linearization).

Hence, you will have to determine

$$\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x_\text{eq}}.$$

If this value is positive then, the equilibrium point is unstable. If it is negative hen the equilibrium point is at least locally asymptotically stable.

Comment: The problem is a bit more complicated than that

Comment: @polfosol: I think the OP is doing a bifurcation analysis. And $a$ is the bifurcation parameter. But let us wait for the OP to explain what he really means.

Comment: MrYouMath is right, a is the bifurcation parameter. My bad, I should have clarified. A typical question would be:
a) Does this equation give a well-defined vector field on a circle. (in the question it uses theta instead of x)
b) Find all fixed points as a varies and sketch the flux diagram.
c) Draw the bifurcation diagram and classify the occurring bifurcations as a varies.

Comment: By the way, stability of equilibrium in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{S}^1$ can be also simply determined just by looking at signs of $f(x; a)$ near the equilibrium. If only qualitative picture is the matter of interest, this could be enough.

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you for the addition:).